# Fourier Series limitations

Tags: limits, fourier-series

What are the limitations of Fourier Series? Can anyone explain me the limitations for both trigonometric form and exponential form?

Comment: Making a truly wild guess as to what you mean, for a function to have a Fourier series, it must have Fourier coefficients.  Those coefficients are given by certain integrals.  Those integrals have to exist.  That could be called a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

1). All periodic functions can't be expressed in terms of Fourier series,but only those which follow dirichlet conditions,
2).  resulting signal(reconstructed) is not exactly the same signal you provide but has the same energy as that of the input signal,since the physical systems respond only to energy of a signal this shouldn't count as a limitation.

3). (if input signal has finite discontinuities) The Gibbs phenomenon: For any finite no of harmonics the reconstructed signal will possess ripples at discontinuity,and the peak amplitude of the ripples remains constant for whatever value you chose for no of harmonics.

4). Regarding trigonometric and exponential forms ,they are just a form for expression either of them are good and equally same .

Hope this solves your question.